# Stacking Views in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to pass one view into another with SwiftUI but I get the following error.

*FormView.Type' is not convertible to '(FormDetails) -> FormView'*

Here is what I am trying to do.  I am trying to create a "Form View" and call it in my "Guitar Details" view.  Here is the code.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**FormDetails.swift**

```
import Foundation
> 
> struct FormDetails: Hashable {
>     let name: String
>      }
> 
> let formData: [FormDetails] = [
>     .init (name: "Simon Ambridge"),
>     .init (name: "Martin"),
>     .init (name: "Fender"),
>     .init (name: "Washburn"),
>     .init (name: "Gibson") ]
```

**FormView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI


struct FormView: View {

    var formView: FormDetails

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Text(formView.name)
        }
    }
}
struct FormView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FormView(formView: formData[0])
    }
}
```

**GuitarDetails.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

struct GuitarDetails: View {

    var selectedGuitar: Guitar

    @State private var zoomed = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Image(selectedGuitar.imageName)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: zoomed ? .fill: .fit)
                    .onTapGesture { withAnimation {self.zoomed.toggle()}}
            }.navigationBarTitle(Text(selectedGuitar.name), displayMode: .inline)
            FormView() ***<----FormView.Type' is not convertible to '(FormDetails) -> FormView'***
        }
    }
}

struct GuitarDetails_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        GuitarDetails(selectedGuitar: guitars[2])
    }
}
```

Comment: You need a `FormDetails` to create a `FormView`, don't you?

Comment: Isn't that the first code file I referenced in my post?

Comment: Yes, you seem to be aware of the fact that you need a `FormDetails` to create a `FormView` in the first code file, but you forgot about that fact in `GuitarDetails`.

Comment: Sorry.  Really new to coding.  I understand I needed to create a stored property in FormView to access the objects in FormDetails.  Are you saying I need to create a stored property in GuitarDetails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Sweeper said, you need to set the `formDetails` property when you create `FormView`. Pass a value into its constructor.

Comment: Guess I don't get it.  I'll move on to something else.  Thanks.

Comment: Like this `FormView(formDetails: formData[0])`

Comment: That doesn't work.  I don't get an option for FormDetails:

Comment: I don't know what you mean.

Comment: Within the GuitarDetails file, I want to call FormView.  I get the error.  When I try to pass in a value, I'm not getting an option for formDetails.  This is what Xcode presents me with.  FormView(formView: <#T##FormDetails#>) FormDetails is a placeholder, but I guess I was under the impression that if the FormDetails were set in the FormView, I wouldn't have to reset them in the GuitarDetails file.

Comment: It looks like you called the variable `formView` inside the `FormView` class. It should probably be called `formDetails` since that's what it holds.

Comment: I got the form to show up in my contentview.swift file when I ran the code. I created a stored property called formFile in the GuitarDetails file.  I called the FormView file and passed in formLine.  I also had to pass in formLine, formData[1] in the GuitarDetail_Preview struct to see to preview.  After that I had to add the following to the NavigationLink. formLine: FormDetails(name: "LSU")).  It work with the static "LSU" string, but I want it to use the names in the formData property in the FormDetails file.  I guess I can work on that next.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I could have just created a form in the GuitarDetails file and set a static property without going through all of that.  I think there is something I am missing regarding the difference between pass by value and pass by reference,